# Python3.11 cannot find/import any package/library

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, package

I upgraded python to 3.11, and installed pyenv, now python can't find ANY package

See numpy is installed:

```
~/Documents/shopping main@431911a0 !1 ?3                                                                                                                                                    Py base 22:24:07
❯ pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.25.0
Summary: Fundamental package for array computing in Python
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: 
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: altair, blis, contourpy, deeplake, gpt-index, gradio, langchain, matplotlib, numcodecs, numexpr, pandas, spacy, thinc, transformers
```

But it can't be imported:

```
~/Documents/shopping main@431911a0 !1 ?3                                                                                                                                                    Py base 22:24:13
❯ python 
Python 3.11.4 (v3.11.4:d2340ef257, Jun  6 2023, 19:15:51) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> exit()
```

my python version:

```
~/Documents/shopping main@431911a0 !1 ?3                                                                                                                                                 8s Py base 22:24:30
❯ which python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.11
```

Any idea what is happening?

Updates: I messed the whole python/pip env, for installing miniconda yesterday. After reinstalling python and pip, here are their latest paths:

```
❯ which pip
pip: aliased to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/pip3


❯ which python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.11
```

How to fix this? Pip list is still showing the package but nothing could be imported